# AngularJS ng-mouseenter not working in child div

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have been using the AngularJS ng-mouseenter and mg-mouseleave and it has been almost the cause of my death. A quick explanation:

```
<div class="characterSum">
    <div class="avatarContainer" ng-mouseenter="showButton = true" ng-mouseout="showButton = false">
        <img ng-src="{{imagePath}}" class="img-thumbnail">
        <div class="addImage" ng-show="showButton && (imagePath == 'images/chars/defaultCharacterAvatar.png')">
            <button class="btn-btn-default">
            Add Character Image
            </button>
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS properties:

```
.avatarContainer {
    max-width: 150px;
    max-height: 150px;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    margin-right:5px;
    position:relative;
}

.characterSum {
    border: 1px;
    min-height:160px;
    position:relative;
}
```

I'm fairly certain it has something to do with my CSS properties. I followed a few instructions to automatically scale an image into a 150 x 150 size so that might explain my CSS properties for those wizards. Anyway, the reason why I think it has something to do with it is because when I add this:

```
<div ng-mouseenter="showButton = true" ng-mouseout"showButton = false">Hi</div>
```

And I add it under the parent class "characterSum", when I  mouse over Hi, the button shows. As soon as I add this under the class "avatarContainer" the child div, it stops working. If I wrap the ENTIRE avatarContainer class with this div so:

```
<div ng-mouseenter="showButton = true" ng-mouseout"showButton = false">
    HI
    <div class="avatarContainer"> ......... </div>
</div>
```

It only shows the button when I go near hi. I added $scope.$watch on showButton to console.log('detected') whenever showButton changes and in every scenario, "detected" is never logged when I go over the img or anything EXCEPT FOR when I go over hi

Does anyone have any ideas on what crazy curse I have been put under? Or if not, I'm willing to use any other way of accomplishing this. (Basically want the button to show whenever the img is moused over). And I have already tried directly applying ng-mouseover to the img element to no avail.

Comment: I started the plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/fX5ii65v0DpOZs4ydUXN?p=preview

Comment: So when the imagePath is that, mouse over shows the button. which bit is exactly what you don't expect?

Comment: Hi thanks for creating a plnkr! When I mouse over the image, the button does not show up at all. Also, everything is wrapped in the container-fluid bootstrap div. For some reason, the plnkr seems to be working though... I will try to replicate the situation in another plnkr

Comment: @PhilipTsang are you able to replicate the issue in plunkr?

Comment: I have not been able to replicate the issue in plunkr unfortunately. A lot if it is that my code depends on alot of post requests (which I think is the problem) and PHP code which plunkr can't do. Im setting up a little mini server it can query from though. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You had a typo, you need to use `ng-mouseleave`instead of `ng-mouseout`

**Markup**

```
<div class="characterSum">
    <div class="avatarContainer" ng-mouseenter="showButton = true" 
     ng-mouseleave="showButton = false">
        <img ng-src="{{imagePath}}" class="img-thumbnail">
        <div class="addImage" ng-show="showButton && (imagePath == 'images/chars/defaultCharacterAvatar.png')">
            <button class="btn-btn-default">
            Add Character Image
            </button>
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I switched to ng-mosueout after reading that ng-mouseout and ng-mouseleave were identical in a last effort hope to save my script. Unfortunately, nothing happened

Comment: could yoj create a plunkr please??